# What does FAB stand for?

Tags: thunderbirds

I've been channelling my inner seven-year-old recently with the aid of some Thunderbirds DVDs, and it has reminded me of a long-forgotten mystery. The initials F.A.B. are used by International Rescue people to mean "I Agree" or "Great" or "I Hear and Obey". But what do these letters stand for?

Comment: relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139152/thunderbirds-f-a-b

Comment: I recall hearing somewhere (can't remember where) that it was potentially "fully acknowledged and briefed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nothing

[Gerry Anderson confirmed to the BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/entertainment/1002177.stm).

> FAB stands for absolutely nothing! In the Sixties when the series was made the abbreviation "fab" as in "fabulous" was all the rage and I just changed it a bit.

<sup>Hat-tip to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139152/thunderbirds-f-a-b) at SF&F</sup>